# Can't connect postgres_exporter to postgresql database

Tags: postgresql, docker, prometheus

I can't connect [postgres_exporter](https://github.com/wrouesnel/postgres_exporter) to postgresql database. I am getting

```
time="2019-04-29T15:37:46Z" level=info msg="Established new database connection to \"localhost:5432\"." source="postgres_exporter.go:767"
time="2019-04-29T15:37:46Z" level=error msg="Error opening connection to database (postgresql://postgres:PASSWORD_REMOVED@localhost:5432/postgres?sslmode=disable): pq: unknown authentication response: 10" source="postgres_exporter.go:1260"
time="2019-04-29T15:37:46Z" level=info msg="Starting Server: :9187" source="postgres_exporter.go:1360"
```

Port is ok, password too. When I am trying to run it as

```
# Start an example database
docker run --net=host -it --rm -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password postgres
# Connect to it
docker run --net=host -e DATA_SOURCE_NAME="postgresql://postgres:password@localhost:5432/postgres?sslmode=disable" wrouesnel/postgres_exporter
```

it works perfectly but there is already postgresql running instance so I can't create new one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're using SCRAM authentication in your database but the `postgres_exporter` doesn't support it yet.

You can either wait for [this issue](https://github.com/wrouesnel/postgres_exporter/issues/231) to be resolved, build the exporter yourself with an updated [lib/pq](https://github.com/lib/pq) package to enable SCRAM support or resort to using md5 authentication.

Comment: It sounds very reasonable and I was thinking about it but when I changed authentication method to md5 in local and host options it doesn't help

```                                                                                                         
local   all             all                                              md5

host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5

```

Answer (score 0):

I also meet this problem. I change localhost to 127.0.0.1 in `DATA_SOURCE_NAME` to resove this problem.11

```
DATA_SOURCE_NAME="postgresql://postgres:password@127.0.0.1:5432/postgres?sslmode=disable"
```